# How can I display a dialog on Currently visible activity on BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: dialog, broadcastreceiver

I have a main Activity (OceanintelligenceActivity). In this activity I register the device for push notifications and also I registered a receiver that shows a Dialog and starts the proper Activity depending on the info sent from my server. This is the code I'm using to register the device and the receiver :

```
protected void gcmRegistration(){

    PMApplication thisApp = PMApplication.getInstance();
    AppDelegate delegate = thisApp.getAppDelegate();
    final Context context = this;
    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);     
    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.     
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    // Let's declare our receiver
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (regId.equals("")) {       
        Log.d("", "Lets register for Push");
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);       
    }else {

      if(GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
          // Skips registration.                          
          String apnsToken = delegate.sso.getAPNSToken();           
          if(!apnsToken.equals(regId)){

            Log.d("", "The Device RegId has changed on GCM Servers");
            // We should let our servers know about this
            ServerUtilities.update(regId, context);
          }


      } else {        

          Log.d("","Is not register on PM Server");               
          // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
          // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
          // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.              
          mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

              @Override
              protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                  boolean registered = ServerUtilities.register(context, regId);
                  // At this point all attempts to register with the app
                  // server failed, so we need to unregister the device
                  // from GCM - the app will try to register again when
                  // it is restarted. Note that GCM will send an
                  // unregistered callback upon completion, but
                  // GCMIntentService.onUnregistered() will ignore it.
                  if (!registered) {
                      GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);
                  }
                  return null;
              }

              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                  mRegisterTask = null;
              }

          };
          mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

      }
    }                         
}
```

This is how I set the receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        Log.d("","BroadcastReceiver onReceive");  
        notificationIntent = GCMIntentService.getNotificationIntent(context);

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        .setMessage(newMessage+". Would you like to see it right now?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {                                                       
                // Show update                                                              
                startActivity(notificationIntent);                                                              
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null).show();                                    
    }
};
```

`GCMIntentService.getNotificationIntent(context)`. This line returns the the Intent with the Activity I want to start.

Whenever there is a notification onReceive gets called but the Dialog only shows if I am on the main activity. So if the app is on a different activity, `onReceive` still gets called but the dialog doesn't show and therefore I can't start the proper activity.

How can I display a dialog on Currently visible activity on BroadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around with this one and searching on google I came across a solution. It is not the best one but it works. I still can't believe there is not an easy way to get the current context in Android. So this is what I did to manage to show the Dialog regardless of what the current activity is : I have a public static property of type Context on my singleton class(AppDelegate) and on each activity I override the onResume method and set the Context to the current activity like this AppDelegate.CURRENT_CONTEXT = this. Then on my dialog : AlertDialog.Builder(AppDelegate.CURRENT_CONTEXT).....